# How can I associate and inbound and outbound soaphandler with each-other

Tags: java, soap, weblogic

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html

How can I associate an inbound `handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext)` call with and outbound `handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext)`.

I've tried a few things, Weblogic doesn't reuse the context object so reference checking doesn't work.  I can't find any property that indicates the request distinctly and therefor I can't seem to create a link between the request and response.

Alternatively is there a better way to get the request and response on web-logic problematically and associated together such that they can be dumped to the database for future  debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this may not work on all implementations of JAX-WS but for weblogic this certainly does.

What I've done

```
public final boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    // Using `Object` type as we don't have any need to import servlet libraries into a JAX-WS library
    Object o = context.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    // o will hold a reference to the request 
    // if inbound.o == outbound.o the request objects are identical and therefor we can associate them.
    return true;
}
```

I don't see why this wouldn't work in other containers but please double check before using this method.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of boiler plate code, but it's not dependent on an app server.

The AttachAttributesFilter adds a startTime and UUID to the attributes. These attributes are then read in LogSoapHandler for inbound and outbound messages.

A simple search in the log will show the input and output for a specific UUID.

```
@WebFilter("/yourwebservice")
public class AttachAttributesFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("STARTTIME", System.currentTimeMillis());
        request.setAttribute("UUID",java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then I use the attributes in a LogSoapHander

```
public class LogSoapHandler implements
        javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messagecontext) {
        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) messagecontext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        String messageID = (String) httpSR.getAttribute("UUID");
        Object startTime = httpSR.getAttribute("STARTTIME");
        try {
            final SOAPMessage message = messagecontext.getMessage();
            String encoding = getMessageEncoding(message);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            boolean fault = (message.getSOAPBody().hasFault());

            message.writeTo(baos);
            String body = (baos.toString(encoding));
            log.info(outbound+"|"+messageID+"|"+startTime+"|"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"|"+body+"|"+fault));

        } catch (SOAPException | IOException ex) {
            //handle your error
        }
        return true;
    }
    private String getMessageEncoding(SOAPMessage msg) throws SOAPException {
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        if (msg.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING) != null) {
            encoding = msg.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING)
                    .toString();
        }
        return encoding;
    }
```

And to be complete the HandlerChain boilder plate :

```
@HandlerChain(file="loghandler.xml")
public class MyWSDL {
..
}
```

loghandler.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains 
    xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler>
            <javaee:handler-class>xxx.LogSoapHandler</javaee:handler-class>
        </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```